# perl regex: All must be present

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing a wordle assistant. Is there a regex format that says "match only if all these letters are present, in any order"?  The character class syntax `[abc]` is an OR operation; I'm looking for the equivalent AND.

For example, "cranberry" would match `/{abc}/`, but "cranny", lacking a 'b', would not.

I'm aware of the answer of `$word =~ /^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/`, and also `$_= $word; /a/ && /b/ && /c/`, but I was wondering if there is anything more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[abc]` means the character must be `a` or `b` or `c`.

To match a character that is `a` and `b` and `c`, you can use the `(?[ ... ])`.<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
(?[ [a] & [b] & [c] ])
```

But of course, you don't want AND. You want

```
(?: a.*b.*c
|   a.*c.*b
|   b.*a.*c
|   b.*c.*a
|   c.*a.*b
|   c.*b.*a
)
```

So `/a/ && /b/ && /c/` is *quite* an elegant solution.

---

1. It's an experimental feature, but one I predict will be accepted without change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a` and `b` and `c` in any order, you do:

```
$matches = ($word =~ /a/ && $word =~ /b/ && $word =~ /c/);
```